# How to Bind a Bean Argument Using a List in JDBI 3

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

I'm trying to use the SqlObject API to store a list of Bean POJOs in Postgres.  My interface looks like this:

```
@UseClasspathSqlLocator
@RegisterBeanMapper(SomeBean.class)
public interface LeadStateDao {

    @SqlUpdate
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    SomeBean update(@BindBean SomeBean bean);

    @SqlUpdate
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    SomeBean upsert(@BindBean SomeBean bean);

    @SqlUpdate
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    int[] batchUpsert(@BindList List<SomeBean> beans);

}
```

I'm compiling with parameters which is why I don't have the argument explicitly named (this is working fine).  The `update` and `upsert` methods work as expected, thanks to `@RegisterBeanMapper`.  However the `batchUpsert` doesn't, and I get:

> **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**: No argument factory registered for 'com.foo.SomeBean@49d11f58' of type class com.foo.SomeBean

Is there a way to bind a bean as an argument, as part of a list, without having to write a custom argument factory?  [The docs](http://jdbi.org/#_supported_argument_types) are frustratingly vague here:

> java.util.Collection and Java arrays (stored as SQL arrays). Some additional setup may be required depending on the type of array element.

Not sure what *"some additional setup"* entails.

Answer (score 3):

I never used @BindList like this (for bulk operations) and I don't know if it is made to be used with beans.

As [the docs](http://jdbi.org/#_binding_arguments_2) say:

> Binding a list of values is done through the @BindList annotation. This will expand the list in a 'a,b,c,d,…​' form. Note that this annotation requires you to use the <binding> notation, unlike @Bind (which uses :binding)

So if you have

```
@BindList List<Long> data
```

as parameter in the interface you will have to use

```
select * from my_data where id in (<data>)
```

as query (note the brackets instead of the colon). I doubt that you can use it with beans at all!